# Search in a list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell

I'm new in Haskell, and i'm having a few problems. 
After reading about high order functions, i was trying solve a few exercises about tuples.

So, i have a list with tuples, something like this:

```
list tup = [("James",19,"SB",2),("Patrick",19,"FDF",4),("Jim",20,"CD",3)]
```

And one of the problems was to compare the position of the tuples, for example : 
get the higher age (snd element in a tuple), like this :

```
higherAge tup
>20
```

What i was trying :

```
higherAge ls = maximum (filter (get2th ls))

get2th (_,a,_,_,_) = a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
maxAge l = maximumBy (compare `on` (\(a,b,c,d) -> b)) l
```

The problem with your solution is that you are not using `filter` correctly. `filter` just removes elements from a list, it can only make your list smaller. What it seems like you wanted to do is use `map`.

The following should also work: `maximum (map get2th) ls`

Comment: Thank's @rafalio, another question, so if i wanted the have a list of all the 4th element of the tuples, can i use map too? Like this : (map get4th), this should return a list with all the 4th element?

Comment: Yep, that will work also! You will actually need to have a separate function to access every element of a tuple as in Haskell you are not able to get an arbitrary of a tuple. Let me know if that helped or if you need anything else or else you can accept :)